# How do I detect if an Android device stores media dates in seconds or milliseconds?

Tags: android, timestamp, android-contentresolver

I have a small issue with different Android devices returning the image taken date time-stamp in either seconds or milliseconds. I use a `Intent.ACTION_PICK` and then use a content resolver to query the result.

I am finding that `MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN` column returns in seconds on a Samsung Galaxy J7, but is milliseconds on a Samsung Edge 7. How can I determine which one a device uses?

Comment: epoc in millis looks like this: 1498812669010. epoc in seconds looks like this 1498812669

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're dealing with photos taken by an Android device, we can assume that there won't dates before the year 2000.

The timestamp for `2000-01-01T00:00Z` is **946684800** seconds (or **946684800000** milliseconds). So, if the value is below `946684800000`, then you can assume it's in seconds.

Of course you can be more precise and instead of year 2000, you can use dates after the [first Android version release](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history), or even discard older versions and consider the last N versions (N can be as arbitrary as you want). Here's the timestamp for the Android versions release dates (all dates based on [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history) - time was set to midnight and offset is **UTC**):

```
2008-09-23T00:00Z: 1222128000000 milliseconds
2009-02-09T00:00Z: 1234137600000 milliseconds
2009-04-27T00:00Z: 1240790400000 milliseconds
2009-09-15T00:00Z: 1252972800000 milliseconds
2009-10-26T00:00Z: 1256515200000 milliseconds
2010-05-20T00:00Z: 1274313600000 milliseconds
2010-12-06T00:00Z: 1291593600000 milliseconds
2011-02-22T00:00Z: 1298332800000 milliseconds
2011-10-18T00:00Z: 1318896000000 milliseconds
2012-07-09T00:00Z: 1341792000000 milliseconds
2013-10-31T00:00Z: 1383177600000 milliseconds
2014-11-12T00:00Z: 1415750400000 milliseconds
2015-10-23T00:00Z: 1445558400000 milliseconds
2016-08-22T00:00Z: 1471824000000 milliseconds
```

Comment: I will use this method for now, thanks for the info. I was hoping there would be a built in way of detecting it, when a user previews an image in the gallery it always seems to be a realistic date, but is that because the device manufacturer implements gallery functionality? Well i'm storing the original time-stamps anyway and only displaying a sanity checked version in the interface. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Well milliseconds would be 1000 times larger.  And all timestamps on the device should be relatively recent-  in the past few years.  So if the number is above say 10 billion, its milliseconds.  If its below, its seconds.  This test will work for the next century or so.